# How find this inequality minimum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}-2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_{i}a_{i+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, sum-of-squares-method

> Let $n$ be a given positive integer, and let $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}\ge 0$ such that $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}=1$.
> Find this  minimum value
> $$a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\cdots+a^2_{n}-2a_{1}a_{2}-2a_{2}a_{3}-2a_{3}a_{4}-\cdots-2a_{n-2}a_{n-1}-2a_{n-1}a_{n}.$$

I think maybe we can use this well known
$$a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\cdots+a^2_{n}\ge a_{1}a_{2}+a_{2}a_{3}+\cdots+a_{n-1}a_{n}+a_{n}a_{1}?$$

But this problem is only
$$-2a_{1}a_{2}-2a_{2}a_{3}-2a_{3}a_{4}-\cdots-2a_{n-2}a_{n-1}-2a_{n-1}a_{n}$$
so I can't it.Thank you for help.

**By the way:**
I don't know this problem have Someone research?if No,I think this is interesting problem.

Comment: Your pattern in the middle equation is unclear.  Should the last term be $a_{n-1}a_n$ instead?  In other words, should it be $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2-2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_ia_{i+1}$?

Comment: Yes,Thank you .I have edit

Comment: Not sure if this will help anyone, but for $n=3$, Wolfram Alpha gives that the minimum is $-\frac{1}{7}$ attained by $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(\frac{2}{7},\frac{3}{7},\frac{2}{7})$, and for $n=4$, the minimum is $-\frac{1}{6}$ attained by $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{6})$.

Comment: For $n>4$, as we can extend by keeping $a_5=a_6=\dots=a_n=0$ to get an upper bound of $-\frac16$ for the minimum.  However proving $F\ge -\frac16$ for $n\ge 4$ is another matter $\frown$.

Comment: @Macavity, I don't see why $n=4$ would be so special. It seems more likely the minimum is a decreasing function of $n$.

Comment: @Casteels Possible, I just said it is an upper bound for the minimum.  However, it so happens that Mathematica suggests the minimum for $n=5$ is also $-\frac16$, which makes it an interesting candidate.

Comment: Oh wow that's interesting. Does Mathematica give you the corresponding values of $a_1,\ldots,a_5$? What about higher values of $n$?

Comment: @Macavity A computer search I just made confirms your guess that the minimum is $-\frac{1}{6}$ for $4 \leq n \leq 8$, and also that this minimum is reached at points where all but four coordinates are zero. In this sense, the $n\geq 4$ case seems to reduce to the $n=4$ case.

Comment: @Casteels  It gave me $(\frac{17}{384}, \frac{27}{128}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{37}{128}, \frac{17}{384})$, but I notice from your e.g. we might as well take $(\frac16, \frac13, \frac13, \frac16, 0)$ for the same result!

Comment: maybe this same problem methods can take some idea? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468874/how-prove-this-inequalitys-x-1-le-x-2-le-cdots-le-x-n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I show below that the minimum is $-\frac{1}{6}$ for $n \geq 4$, and $-\frac{1}{7}$ when $n =  3$.

If we put

$$
Q_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_n)=
a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\cdots+a^2_{n}-2a_{1}a_{2}-2a_{2}a_{3}-2a_{3}a_{4}-\cdots-2a_{n-2}a_{n-1}-2a_{n-1}a_{n}
$$

and

$$
R_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_n)=Q_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)+\frac{(a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots +a_n)^2}{6}
$$

then  for $n\geq 4$, we have the identity

$$
R_n(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n)=
\frac{1}{42}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}a_k-5a_{n-1}+7a_n\bigg)^2
+\frac{1}{28}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}2a_k-5a_{n-2}+4a_{n-1}\bigg)^2
+\frac{1}{4}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n-4}2a_k-2a_{n-3}+a_{n-2}\bigg)^2
$$

Since $Q_n(0,\ldots, 0,\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{6})=-\frac{1}{6}$,
we see that the minimum is $-\frac{1}{6}$ for $n\geq 4$.

For $n=3$, the minimum is $-\frac{1}{7}$ attained at
$(\frac{2}{7},\frac{3}{7},\frac{2}{7})$ (thanks Macavity) because of

$$
Q_3(a_1,a_2,a_3)+\frac{(a_1+a_2+a_3)^2}{7}=
\frac{1}{56}\bigg(a_1-6a_2+8a_3\bigg)^2
+\frac{1}{8}\bigg(-3a_1+2a_2\bigg)^2
$$

Comment: Oh,It's very very nice!How can you found this $R_{n}(x)$? +1 Thank you

Comment: @math110 The problem is homogeneous in $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$, so it is natural to define $R=Q+\frac{1}{6}(\ldots)^2$ (once you have guessed that the minimum is $-\frac{1}{6}$). Then you apply the Gauss method to write the quadratic form as a sum of squares

Comment: Very nice! +1...

Comment: oh,I know,Thank you,It's nice methods!

Comment: Please check your identity. I found that it is true for $n=4, 5$, however it is not true for $n=6$. Actually, for $n=6$, if your identity is true, since $R_6$ is sum of squares, we know that $R_6\ge 0$ for all real numbers. However this is not true. Let $a_1 = -1/6, \ a_2 = 0, \ a_3 = 1/4, \ a_4 = 2/5,\ a_5 = 1/3, \ a_6 = 1/6$. We have $R_6 = -\frac{593}{21600} < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

In another post [How find this minimum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}a_{i+1},a_{n+1}=a_{1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564900/how-find-this-minimum-sum-i-1na2-i-2-sum-i-1na-ia-i1-a-n1?rq=1),  one wants to find the minimum of $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^n a_i a_{i+1}$ (denote $a_{n+1}=a_1$).
In that problem, Ewan Delanoy's solution is true for $n=6$.
You will see that $Q_6 - 2a_6a_1 + \frac{1}{6}(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5+a_6)^2$ is non-negative for real numbers,
however, $Q_6 + \frac{1}{6}(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5+a_6)^2$ is not non-negative for real numbers. See the last paragraph below.

**Previously written**

I think that Ewan Delanoy's solution is true for $n=3, 4, 5$ but not true for $n=6$.

Let $Q_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i a_{i+1}$.

For $n=3$, the minimum is $-1/7$ attained at $(2/7, 3/7, 2/7)$ because
$$Q_3 + \frac{1}{7}(a_1+a_2+a_3)^2 
= \frac{1}{56}(a_1 - 6a_2 + 8a_3)^2 + \frac{1}{8}(-3a_1 + 2a_2)^2.$$

For $n=4$, the minimum is $-1/6$ at $(1/6, 1/3, 1/3, 1/6)$ because
\begin{align}
&Q_4 + \frac{1}{6}(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4)^2\\
 =\ & \frac{1}{42}(a_1 + a_2 - 5a_3 + 7a_4)^2
+ \frac{1}{28}(2a_1-5a_2 + 4a_3)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(-2a_1+a_2)^2.
\end{align}

For $n= 5$, the minimum is $-1/6$ at $(1/6, 1/3, 1/3, 1/6, 0)$ because
\begin{align}
&Q_5 + \frac{1}{6}(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5)^2\\
 =\ & \frac{1}{42}(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 - 5a_4 + 7a_5)^2
+ \frac{1}{28}(2a_1+2a_2-5a_3 + 4a_4)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(2a_1-2a_2+a_3)^2.
\end{align}

Note that all $Q_3 + \frac{1}{7}(a_1+a_2+a_3)^2$, $Q_4 + \frac{1}{6}(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4)^2$
and $Q_5 + \frac{1}{6}(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5)^2$ can be written as
sum of squares $\sum_{k=1}^m f_k^2$ where $f_k, \forall k$ is a polynomial. Actually, all of them are non-negative for real numbers.
However, this is not true for $n=6$, i.e., 
$R_6 = Q_6 + \frac{1}{6}(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5+a_6)^2$
can not be written as sum of squares $\sum_{k=1}^m f_k^2$ where $f_k, \forall k$ is a polynomial.
This is because $R_6$ is not non-negative for real numbers.
Let $a_1 = -1/6, \ a_2 = 0, \ a_3 = 1/4, \ a_4 = 2/5,\ a_5 = 1/3, \ a_6 = 1/6$.
We have $R_6 = -\frac{593}{21600} < 0$.

Although $R_6$ is not non-negative for real number, it is non-negative for $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6\ge 0$. Indeed, we have
\begin{align}
&Q_6 + \frac{1}{6}(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5+a_6)^2 \\
= \ & \frac{1}{2}(a_1 - a_2 + a_3 - a_4 + a_5 - a_6)^2 +
\frac{1}{2}(a_1 - a_3 + a_4 - a_6)^2\\
&\quad +\frac{1}{6}(a_1 - 2a_2 + a_3 + a_4 - 2a_5 + a_6)^2 + 2a_1a_6.
\end{align}
Thus, the minimum is $-1/6$ attained at $(1/6, 1/3, 1/3, 1/6, 0, 0)$.

Answer (score -1):

You almost did the problem yourself, just left out a few bits:

Assume, without loss of generality,

$$a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \dots \geq a_n$$

By the rearrangement inequality,

$$\implies a_1^2 + a_2^2 \dots a_n^2 \geq a_1a_2 + a_2a_3 \dots a_{n-1}a_n + a_na_1$$

Clearly, the required will be minimum if equality holds true above.

This will happen when

$$a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = \dots  = a_n = a$$

This means, the maximum value of the inequality is:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n a^2 - 2a^2 = -na^2$$

Since, from the first equation,

$$na = 1$$

$$a = \frac{1}{n}$$

Therefore, the minimum is,

$$-n\cdot\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = -\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: This solution is wrong,But thank you all the same

Comment: Why is it wrong?

Comment: @Gerard the polynomial is not fully symmetric in $a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_n$, so you cannot assume $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \ldots a_n$. So what you’ve done is basically computing the minimum over a subset of the initial set.

Comment: @Gerard There are only $n-1$ terms being subtracted, not $n$; further, $a_1$ and $a_n$ each occur only once in the subtracted terms, while all others occur twice.

Comment: The main issue to me is rather: if $A \ge B$, with a certain equality case $X$, you can't say that $A - 2B$ must attain minimum when $X$ happens, without more explanation.

Comment: For a concrete e.g., let $n=10$.  You suggest the minimum is $-\frac1{10}$.  However using Casteels 4-tuple, $(\frac16, \frac13, \frac13, \frac16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$ gives you a value of $-\frac16$, which is lower than your minimum.

Comment: I'm sorry for my answer. As all of you have pointed out above, it is quite incorrect. I misinterpreted the OP's question, I believe.