# How do I prove this equation?

Tags: calculus, summation

Let $$
Q_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_n)=
a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\cdots+a^2_{n}-2a_{1}a_{2}-2a_{2}a_{3}-2a_{3}a_{4}-\cdots-2a_{n-2}a_{n-1}-2a_{n-1}a_{n}-2a_{n}a_{1}.
$$

Show that:

$$
R_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_n)=Q_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)+\frac{(a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots +a_n)^2}{6}.
$$

For $n\geq 6$, we have the identity
$$
R_n(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n)=
\frac{1}{42}\bigg(-5a_1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}a_k-5a_{n-1}+7a_n\bigg)^2
+\frac{1}{28}\bigg(-3a_1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-3}2a_k-5a_{n-2}+4a_{n-1}\bigg)^2
+\frac{1}{4}\bigg(-a_1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-4}2a_k-2a_{n-3}+a_{n-2}\bigg)^2
$$

This question is from here:[How find this minimum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}a_{i+1},a_{n+1}=a_{1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564900/how-find-this-minimum-sum-i-1na2-i-2-sum-i-1na-ia-i1-a-n1)

and I found that the coefficient $a_{2}$ and $a_{3}$  is wrong, where $R_{n}$. How is it found? Would you someone explain this, please?Thank you

Comment: ([tag:functional-equivations]) is definitely a wrong tag for this. Just read the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/functional-equations/info). But I am not sure, what the correct tags for this question should be.